# Artisan Laravel Unexpected end of file when making controller

Tags: laravel, controllers, laravel-artisan

I am following a PluralSight tutorial on Laravel and I am at a point were I need to add controllers. I put this into the command to work with artisan:

```
C:\wamp\www\laravel>php artisan make:controller ProductController
```

And then I get:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
syntax error, unexpected end of file
```

I have no idea what could be wrong as I am new to Laravel / Artisan, any help is appreciated.

Edit: I installed laravel this way

```
  composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist
```

Probable Fix: Check syntax... Didn't realize this could stop artisan.

Comment: Just to be sure, you have run `composer install` and have a `vendor` directory in the root of your project, correct?

Comment: also, artisan will fail if something in your app is not passing the syntax check

Comment: @Jarry is right, where is the ErrorException happening?

Comment: When I installed I used the laravel documentation like so 'composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist'

Comment: Run Artisan with the verbose flag. It may give you a file and line number of the offending syntax error.

Comment: @Jarry I think you are right as I have been following and trying to type things as I listened to the tutorial. I will check in the morning